# phpMailer $mail->AddReplyTo() is hurting the spam rating?

Tags: php, phpmailer, spam

I have a league management website where I allow a league admin to send emails to all of his players from my server. I use php with phpMailer to send the emails from my server. My website has a good reputation and phpMailer has done a good job for many years.

My problem is that I am being penalized on my spam rating because I use the phpMailer function $mail->AddReplyTo(). I use this so the receiver of the email can reply back to the admin that sent the message.

My spam rating without using $mail->AddReplyTo() is 9.5/10
Adding $mail->AddReplyTo() results in a 7.2/10 rating.

Is there something I can do to prevent this penality?

Here's my code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Encoding = 'base64';
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
if($server_box == ''){$server_box = LEAGUE_ADMIN_EMAIL;}

try {

$mail->Host = "localhost";
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "localhost";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Username = $server_box;
$mail->Password = $box_password;
$mail->AddReplyTo($senderEmail, "$senderName"); 
$mail->AddAddress("$to_address", "$to_name"); 
$mail->SetFrom($server_box, "$senderName"); 
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($HTML);
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; // needed this to stop a SMTP connection error
$mail->AddCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:".HELPDESK_EMAIL."?subject=Unsubscribe>, <".$unsubUrl.">");

$mail->Send();
 }
```

Comment: Why do you need to use reply-to at all? Usually the main reason for doing that is when you are substituting the submitter's name, but you're not doing that here. You're better off sending from a correct *from* name instead. Beyond that, spam ratings are entirely at the whim of the receiver, and there isn't much you can do about their decisions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I add the reply-to address so that the administrator who is using my server to send the mail will get a reply if the receiver sends one. Otherwise, if the receiver replied back, it would go back to my server.

Comment: where did you test the rating?